# android place picker or google maps api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

i want to see all near places and use place picker for that, but when i start app picker appears and disappears, i cant understand why, help please, thx and sorry for my eng.
If you have some offers how i can see near places without picker, please tell me =)

UPD:
Tried change  com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY on com.google.android.geo.API_KEY dont help.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btPlacesAPI;
private TextView tvPlaceAPI;

private int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvPlaceAPI = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_place_id);

    btPlacesAPI = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_ppicker);
    btPlacesAPI.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
            try {

                startActivityForResult(builder.build(MainActivity.this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);


            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this,data);
            String toastMsg = String.format(
                    "Place: %s \n" +
                            "Alamat: %s \n" +
                            "Latlng %s \n", place.getName(), place.getAddress(), place.getLatLng().latitude+" "+place.getLatLng().longitude);
            tvPlaceAPI.setText(toastMsg);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ActivityMap"></activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAej54bA3F_PnWkVYX1XfKoEevcfC5RtXM" />


</application>
```

Comment: Looks like an exact duplicate of [Place Picker automatically closing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359861/place-picker-automatically-closing)  Basically, use `com.google.android.geo.API_KEY` instead of  `com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY` in your manifest.

Comment: what is the error you get in the logs?

Comment: nothing errors, just cloth the picker and all

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="Server_key" />
```

Key should be server key instead of android api key
refer this link http://www.androidrey.com/google-places-api-for-android-place-picker/