# Places Api activity closes immediately?

Tags: android, google-places-api

Im making an android mapsActivity application,Ive enabled Places API in the console and maps sdk for android.But the places activity still closes after launching? Ive tried all the solutions in the following links but still no help .. Am i doing something wrong here ? Also what is the difference between Places API and Places Sdk for android ? Are they both same and different versions or 2 different Apis ?

[place picker close immediately after activity start (google places api)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449985/place-picker-close-immediately-after-activity-start-google-places-api)

[Place Picker automatically closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359861/place-picker-automatically-closing)

Dependency in my gradle:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mapsactivity">

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Logcat:

```
    2019-04-23 16:00:01.933 1823-4421/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PICK_PLACE pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.places.ui.placepicker.PlacePickerActivity (has extras)} from uid 10179 and from pid 27592
2019-04-23 16:00:01.938 1823-4421/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityStartTrigger: not whiteListedcom.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.places.ui.placepicker.PlacePickerActivity/16089020
2019-04-23 16:00:01.939 1823-4421/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.places.ui.placepicker.PlacePickerActivity/16089020
2019-04-23 16:00:01.960 1823-4421/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.places.ui.placepicker.PlacePickerActivity/16089020
2019-04-23 16:00:01.974 1823-4421/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 27752:com.google.android.gms.ui/u0a15 for activity com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.places.ui.placepicker.PlacePickerActivity
2019-04-23 16:00:02.307 27752-27752/? I/AppCompatDelegate: Failed to instantiate custom view inflater android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater. Falling back to default.
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378)
        at afb.a(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):5)
        at afb.onCreateView(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):1)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:779)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:737)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onResourcesLoaded(DecorView.java:2144)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2741)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2847)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2138)
        at afb.q(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):8)
        at afb.b(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):65)
        at dvj.setContentView(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):1)
        at com.google.android.places.ui.placepicker.PlacePickerChimeraActivity.onCreate(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):19)
        at com.google.android.chimera.Activity.publicOnCreate(Unknown Source:0)
        at dvo.onCreate(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):6)
        at ppa.onCreate(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):2)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7314)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7305)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3056)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1774)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7038)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:523)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:836)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar", zip file "/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.gms-uUjbB6k4icCk-HzbRi6tpw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.google.android.gms-uUjbB6k4icCk-HzbRi6tpw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.google.android.gms-uUjbB6k4icCk-HzbRi6tpw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378) 
        at afb.a(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):5) 
        at afb.onCreateView(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):1) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:779) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:737) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onResourcesLoaded(DecorView.java:2144) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2741) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2847) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2138) 
        at afb.q(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):8) 
        at afb.b(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):65) 
        at dvj.setContentView(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):1) 
        at com.google.android.places.ui.placepicker.PlacePickerChimeraActivity.onCreate(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):19) 
        at com.google.android.chimera.Activity.publicOnCreate(Unknown Source:0) 
        at dvo.onCreate(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):6) 
        at ppa.onCreate(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):2) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7314) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7305) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3056) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1774) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7038) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:523) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:836) 
2019-04-23 16:00:02.894 1823-4421/? V/WindowManager: Changing focus from null to Window{51b1263 u0 com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.places.ui.placepicker.PlacePickerActivity}
2019-04-23 16:00:03.078 1823-2068/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.places.ui.placepicker.PlacePickerActivity: +1s112ms
2019-04-23 16:00:03.684 3152-5161/? E/Volley: [103] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/placesandroid/v1/placePicker?key=AIzaSyB-PM7l1fJIxvCY6yFItebHa_30u4PmKKM
2019-04-23 16:00:03.690 3152-27601/? E/Places: Places API for Android does not seem to be enabled for your app. See https://developers.google.com/places/android/signup for more details.
2019-04-23 16:00:03.691 3152-27601/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=65, operation=PlacePickerQuota
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED, resolution=null}]
        at bear.b(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):1)
        at beaq.a(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):5)
        at zgb.run(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):27)
        at bgot.run(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):2)
        at rrt.b(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):32)
        at rrt.run(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):21)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at rxx.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2019-04-23 16:00:03.692 27752-27752/? E/Places: Place Picker closing due to PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED
2019-04-23 16:00:03.748 1823-3834/? V/WindowManager: Changing focus from Window{51b1263 u0 com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.places.ui.placepicker.PlacePickerActivity} to Window{d5594ef u0 com.example.mapsactivity/com.example.mapsactivity.MapsActivity}
2019-04-23 16:00:04.097 3152-5164/? E/Volley: [105] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/placesandroid/v1/search?key=AIzaSyB-PM7l1fJIxvCY6yFItebHa_30u4PmKKM
2019-04-23 16:00:04.100 3152-27601/? E/Places: Places API for Android does not seem to be enabled for your app. See https://developers.google.com/places/android/signup for more details.
2019-04-23 16:00:04.100 3152-27601/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=65, operation=SearchPlaces
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED, resolution=null}]
        at bear.b(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):1)
        at beat.a(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):23)
        at zgb.run(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):27)
        at bgot.run(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):2)
        at rrt.b(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):32)
        at rrt.run(:com.google.android.gms@16089020@16.0.89 (040406-239467275):18)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at rxx.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: it happen when it reached the daily usage limit .

Comment: It hasnt. ive generated a new key too. In my console im getting 0 requests for this API

Comment: Add the place sdk dependency with question .

Comment: Please check . Ive added the my dependency.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/54829363/8101634

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the people who still face this issue. My issue was with the key . The apis were enabled on my account but NOT ON my key. I made a new key and it works fine now.