# Android Google Places API "PLACES_API_QUOTA_FAILED"

Tags: android, google-places-api

Ok, so I am kinda new to Google maps/geo etc. So I went to the Google console, added an application, enabled **"Places API for Android"**, copy pasted the API key like this :

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="API-KEY" />
```

I have an activity where I did

`mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, 0 /* clientId */, this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .build();`

Copy pasted the adapter from the samples code.
Everything compiled fine, autocompletetextview was setup properly and all.

Now when I started typing, it throws an error immediately
`Error getting autocomplete prediction API call: Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_QUOTA_FAILED, resolution=null}`

I searched and searched and guess what, google doesn't even have this error code in their documentation! Has anybody faced this? Am I missing something here?

P.S - I added the app a day ago so definitely my quota is not over. Also its a different error code for exhausted quota.

Comment: There are two auto complete apis there for web and for android  check which one you are using and add appropriate API KEY make sure in Developer Console you have enabled the right one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry about this confusing error code—we're working on getting that fixed.

This could be due to an incorrect certificate fingerprint in your Developers Console configuration. Would you mind double checking the instructions at https://developers.google.com/places/android/signup#find-cert?

Let me know if that works.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (I was using a debug key and trying to make it work in a different computer). The error code is in deed confusing.

Answer (score 2):

So, the problem was, I had generated an "Android Key" (which I thought was logical because I was developing an android app). That didn't work and gave me this confusing code.
Then I went back, deleted that key, and generated a "Server Key" and pasted that code in the app manifest. Guess what, it worked!

Most peculiar behavior and this step is not even mentioned in the documentation as to why this is logical.

Comment: You don't have to delete the Android Key, you just need to create a Server Key.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. 
For me the problem was fixed by enabling the api via:

https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=placesandroid&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&reusekey=true

and regenerate key as a **server** one

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was generated because a new sdk and android studio install.
So, just following the steps in the Google tutorial solved the problem: https://developers.google.com/places/android/signup#find-cert

Answer (score 0):

I changed my package name during the development stage. After changing the package name on the Developers Console api key apps I came across this error. The solution was to simply wait 5 minutes or so after changing the key in the Developers Console. The Developers Console does clearly state this but it's easy to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me when using `genymotion`. This also happens on devices and emulator. With me I choose `Run` option from `android studio. Which does not build a **signed APK**. Google Map services need a signed apk for running.

Build a signed APK and drag and drop it into `genymotion` (install it using `adb install`) for it to work.