# android - Google places opens the map on closes after 1 sec

Tags: java, android

Im creating an intent to an activity by clicking on a button which should open google places, but it closes again really fast and says no location selected, and returns to the main activity, and then nothing happens if i click again.

My api should be fine, I have checked that it's the correct SHA1-fingerprint thats connected to the api key.

The result code is 2

It worked earlier in the activity before this one, but I needed it to open when i click on a button instead, and now when I try to open this new activity as an intent it wont work.

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
int status;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_events);

    status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(status)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this,
                    100).show();
        }
    }
    if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 199;
        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
        Context context = this;
        try {
            startActivityForResult(builder.build(context), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    System.out.println("Result code: " + resultCode);
    System.out.println("Request code: " + requestCode);
    if (requestCode == 100) {
        status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    }
    if (requestCode == 199) {

        //process Intent......
        if (data != null) {
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
            String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
            Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            String toastMsg = ("No location selected.");
            Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

}

This is from the intent which create the new intent to maps

```
   public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MapActivity.class);
       startActivity(i);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its happening because of you are using old method of getPlace

try to swap the arguments, by changing it from:

```
Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
```

to

```
Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(getContext(), data);
```

---

**Update #2**

Enable Google places API in the developer console and add these lines to AndroidManifest

```
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
  android:value="ADD_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE" />
```

---

**Update #3**

after some search, it looks like there is others having same issue. Look at these links:

https://github.com/zhangtaii/react-native-google-place-picker/issues/21

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32751164/

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/issues/13

Comment: in PlacePicker cannot be applied to

Comment: Ok, try to give the context is being called on, this, getContext()

Comment: I just added some more lines in the description, maybe it helps. because it has been working, it just stop working when I try to put it in a new activity

Comment: Can you post the code, where you creating the intent?

Comment: its added to description :)

Comment: No, all I know is that it gives a wrong result code, it shouldn't be 2. But it makes no sence, if I make this code on the intent before it works, but when try making a new intent with the exactly same code it wont work

Comment: The user and pass is just made in a singleton
User: admin
Pass: 1234

Comment: Ohhh, it seems to be working now. I was after a friend have working with the project the package name i manifest was changed and therefore it didn't work.
Thank you so much for the help, the link in update 3 helped alot :)

Comment: sounds great! glad that it got fixed!