# PlacePicker issue, PlacePicker closes in just a second, after opening

Tags: android

I want to implement placepicker, but I have a problem, for some reason after I make the intent, the map appears but after one sec disappear. So, I can't pick a place.
I put my code:

```
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

try {
    startActivityForResult(builder.build(MainActivity.this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and the onActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
            String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
            Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

After I make  the intent after one sec goes in onActivityResult, where resultCode e 2 and data is null.
And I have a second question, after I resolve this, I would like to make a custom PlacePicker, if somebody can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google PlacePicker Closes Immediately After Launch with resultCode 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243930/google-placepicker-closes-immediately-after-launch-with-resultcode-2)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In the future, please search for your question before asking it because it looks like someone already asked the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243930/google-placepicker-closes-immediately-after-launch-with-resultcode-2

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be a missing API Key/License.

Check your developer console to make sure that Places API For Android is enabled along with Places API and that your API Key is correct.

A quick Google search revealed the following:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/issues/13

https://github.com/zhangtaii/react-native-google-place-picker/issues/21

and another question on StackOverflow, [Google PlacePicker Closes Immediately After Launch with resultCode 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243930/google-placepicker-closes-immediately-after-launch-with-resultcode-2)